# What is the difference between Beziehung and Verhältnis?

Tags: difference

Listed below are the definitions provided by Wiktionary.org:

- Beziehung

  - relation, relationship, connection
- Verhälntis

  - relation, ratio
  - relationship
  - affair (adulterous relationship)

Is there a guideline or rule for when to use these words?  Would both words be acceptable to describe the following: familial relationship or romantic relationship?